# Installing Python and Jupyter on AWS EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a school project along with my team where we have to analyze large data sets using Python. The data is in the form of images (jpeg files). Since the analysis involves images we will be using TensorFlow, OpenCV etc. As the data set is large we are exploring running Python on EC2 and storing the data set on S3. Is there any wiki or guide that can help us with:
1) Set up Python (3.5) on EC2 and connect to S3 bucket where the files are stored.
2) Create a multi-user environment where all the team members (five) can access the server remotely and run tests against the data set/files.
My skill level on AWS is basic at best. Greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Use _awscli_ (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) to copy from/to S3

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you would want to use the AWS CLI, but there are several things that you would need to setup first.

1. Create an account and enter the IAM console to create your users. I assume you would want to assign them all to the same group and define one permission policy for all of them. You should need access to only EC2 and S3. You will need a complete working knowledge of the [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) service (it is relatively small).
2. Create a role so that your EC2 instance can get access to S3. Follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html) tutorial.
3. Use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access your EC2 instance. The installation/development workflow should mimic a linux workflow very closely.